# Are there any functions for long-swipe(full-swipe) in Swift UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, swipe

I want a full swipe just by a short swipe gesture(normal swipe gesture).
But I don't know the function that causes the long swipe or the function that detects the swipe gesture.

Here's the example.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have a look here. They’re called “swipeActions”. https://programmingwithswift.com/uitableviewcell-swipe-actions-with-swift/

Comment: Thank you but I already saw it. Sadly, they don't have what I want. I want FULL-COVER swipe just by one short swipe.

Comment: Oh, then you'd have to do that yourself. But also... think about what your users expect. They are iOS users and are used to how iOS works. If you change that in any way then you are breaking the expectation of your users. This will result in a negative user experience. Think carefully about changing the default way that the standard iOS controls work.